# Verificar se todos os objetos da classe que estende RealmObject estão vazios

Tags: java, android, realmdb

Minha `Book.class` que estende `realmobject`

```
public class Book extends RealmObject {
    private String title;
    private String author;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
}
```

Como faço para descobrir se esses objetos estão vazios?

Eu tentei:

```
public boolean hasBook() {

    return !realm.allObjects(Book.class).isEmpty();
}
```

Mas não funcinou.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa de uma instância de RealmResults para fazer essa verificação.

Ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
RealmResults<Book> books = realm.where(Book.class).findAll();
if(books.isEmpty())
```